# how to configure types for Typescript and Vue 3.0 (bundler and runtime compilation)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, parceljs

I'm following the Vue [getting started guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#getting-started), and would like to make this simple example work:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="counter">
  Counter: {{ counter }}
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
const Counter = {
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(Counter).mount('#counter')
```

To do this I've installed:

```
npm install vue@next
```

and I'm importing it with:

```
import * as Vue from "vue";
```

The HTML snippet and Typescript script are put into an `index.html` file. This is bundled with `parcel` and hosted locally with `serve`.

Vue ships Typescript types and if I import Vue like this, they are correctly picked up.
However, when I open the hosted project, there's an error message:

```
Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.
```

I followed the advice and changed my import to:

```
import * as Vue from "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler";
```

This makes the sample code work as expected.
But now the typing information is lost.

What is the correct way to combine Vue with Typescript and a bundler, while allowing for runtime compilation?

Comment: I created some projects using vue cli 4+ typescript and they work fine, but i have never worked with parcel, [one](https://github.com/boussadjra/vue3-router-tree) of my project

Comment: Did you solve this ??